# How to resolve errors to connect microsoft share-point using mule integration?

Tags: mule, sharepoint-2013

PFB is the sample code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:objectstore="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore" xmlns:sfdc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:json="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json" xmlns:sharepoint="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint/current/mule-sharepoint.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/json/current/mule-json.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sfdc/current/mule-sfdc.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/objectstore/current/mule-objectstore.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd">


    <file:connector name="Write_File" writeToDirectory="${output.path}" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File" outputAppend="true"/>

    <sharepoint:online-connection-config name="Microsoft_SharePoint_2013__Online_Connection1" username="${Username}" password="${Password}" siteUrl="${SiteUrl}" disableCnCheck="true" doc:name="Microsoft SharePoint 2013: Online Connection">
        <reconnect frequency="10000" count="5"/>
    </sharepoint:online-connection-config>
    <flow name="all-files-query" initialState="started">
        <poll doc:name="Poll">
            <fixed-frequency-scheduler frequency="${polling.frequency}" startDelay="${polling.delay}" timeUnit="HOURS"/>
            <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
        </poll>
        <sharepoint:file-query config-ref="Microsoft_SharePoint_2013__Online_Connection" query="dsql:SELECT Author,CheckInComment,CheckOutType,CheckedOutByUser,ContentTag,CustomizedPageStatus,ETag,Exists,Length,Level,LinkingUrl,ListItemAllFields,LockedByUser,MajorVersion,MinorVersion,ModifiedBy,Name,ServerRelativeUrl,TimeCreated,TimeLastModified,Title,UIVersion,UIVersionLabel,UniqueId,Versions FROM 'Sell sheetsBrochures' ORDER BY TimeLastModified DESC LIMIT ${sharepoint.file.fetch.number}" doc:name="Modified File query "/>
        <logger message="Completed query" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

I'm getting below error while integrating with microsoft sharepoint.

I deleted and added the sharepoint connector to ensure add the required jar file but still getting the error. This is how i resolve org.xml.sax.SAXParseException error in case of other components like salesforce and objectstore.

```
WARN  2017-10-06 13:55:25,868 [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Ignored XML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint/3.7/mule-sharepoint.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaWarning(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

ERROR 2017-10-06 13:55:25,983 [main] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'sharepoint:online-connection-config'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context":property-placeholder, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":ref, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":global-property, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":configuration, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":notifications, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-extension, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-agent, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-security-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-transaction-manager, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-shared-connector, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-exception-strategy, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-flow-construct, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":sub-flow, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-model, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-interceptor-stack, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-filter, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-transformer, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":processor-chain, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-empty-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":invoke, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":set-payload, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-global-intercepting-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":custom-queue-store, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-processing-strategy}' is expected.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
```

Comment: yes the schema  destination for the SharePoint connector are missing or their jars and not present in the build path of the project , can you please add your XML of your project for better understanding  of your issue and also do check if the jar for SharePoint connector is present in build path

Comment: I have updated the code, i could see libraries in build path

Answer (score 0):

Looking from your exception , your applications seems to be searching for SharePoint verion 3.7

> http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sharepoint/3.7/mule-sharepoint.xsd

There seems to be no such version , the last was **2.3.0** as shown [here.](https://github.com/mulesoft/mulesoft-docs/blob/master/release-notes/v/latest/microsoft-sharepoint-2013-connector-release-notes.adoc)

Do change your **jar** file in your project as show in this [MuleSoft Docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/working-with-multiple-versions-of-connectors#changing-the-connector-version-on-an-existing-application)